My CNN Can Only Take In Multiple Images, How Do I Make It Able To Take In 1 Image?
I was creating a CNN for the MNIST dataset. I noticed that training worked fine but when I tried to put in only one image, a shape error was returned. And when I changed the in_feature so it can take in only one image, the train loop stopped working.
How would I make it so the CNN can take in both multiple and single images? (I'm pretty new to CNN's so I don't have a complete but solid grasp on them)
Here is my model:
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_channels: int, output_features: int):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=input_channels,
                      out_channels=16,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3), # Height and Width of Kernel
                      stride=1, # determines how many squares or pixels the kernel skips when it move across the image,
                      padding=1), # adds additional rows and columns of pixels around the edges of the input data so that the size of the output feature map is the same as the size of the input data.

            nn.ReLU(),

            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16,
                      out_channels=16,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=1,
                      padding=1),

            nn.ReLU(),

            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2)) # Scales Down The Image
        )

        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16,
                      out_channels=16,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=1,
                      padding=1),

            nn.ReLU(),

            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16,
                      out_channels=16,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=1,
                      padding=1),

            nn.ReLU(),

            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2))
        )

        self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=16 * 7 * 7, out_features=output_features)
        )



    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)

        return x

model = Net(input_channels=1 ,output_features=10)

And Here Is My Training Code:
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
import time

start = time.time()

model.to(device)

epochs = 3

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch}\n---------")
    train_loss = 0

    # Training
    model.train()

    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

        y_logits = model(X)

        loss = loss_fn(y_logits, y)

        train_loss += loss.item()

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

    train_loss /= len(train_dataloader)

    print(f"Cross Entropy Train Loss: {train_loss: .5f}")

    # Testing

    test_loss = 0

    model.eval()

    with torch.inference_mode():
        for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(test_dataloader):
            y_logits = model(X)

            loss = loss_fn(y_logits, y)



            test_loss += loss.item()

        test_loss /= len(test_dataloader)

    print(f"Cross Entropy Test Loss: {test_loss: .5f}")


end = time.time()

print(f"Train Time on {device.upper()}, {round(end-start, 5)} seconds")

And Finally, Here is My Error When Try To Input A Single Image:
image, label = train[0]

model(image)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in 
forward(self, input)
    114 
    115     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 116         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    117 
    118     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (16x49 and 784x10)


What happens when you do model([image]) instead?

It seem the problem is with image dimension. Try sampling/de-sampling your image to get a smaller/bigger image.

You should might the model somewhere, something like model = NN(?, ?). Would you please update your question with that as well?
